# Hair stylist: long is out and short is in

Tags: meaning

The following sentence seems cryptic to me. Can you please demystify that?

> Hair stylist to his customer: "Long is out and short is in. Shall we try the latter then?"

Comment: In this context, _in_ is [Definition #28](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in) (i.e., _fashionable_), and _out_ is [Definition #20](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/out) (i.e., not in vogue, no longer fashionable). With so many options, though, I can see why these would be difficult to pinpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long hair is out of fashion, short is in (fashionable) , so the hair stylist suggest a short haircut.

Answer (score 1):

In English, adjectives can be treated as nouns. In this case, the adjective serving as a noun denotes some surrounding abstraction which is tied to the adjective, or else it continues to function as an adjective, and implicitly applies to something contextually obvious and relevant to the speaker and listener.

> Thin is in. [Regarding a thin body as good is a popular trend.]
>
> Slow and right beats quick and wrong. [Correctness is more important than speed, in giving an answer, making something, or solving a problem, etc.]
>
> I don't do sad. [I don't wallow in sadness. Or: [Actor] I don't portray sad characters.]
>
> Short is in. [In the context of a hair salon, short obviously refers to shortness of hair, not shortness in general or shortness of stature.]